# Show legend for two plots in one

Tags: python, pandas, charts, seaborn

I have a problem. How could I show the legend? With `legend=True` that didn't work. And how could I change the y-axis label ?

```py
d = {'month': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'price': [79.00, 80.00, 90.00, 20.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'month': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'available ': [5000, 8000,5000, 7000]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
plt1 = sns.lineplot(x = 'month',y = 'available', 
                  data = df2,color="red",legend=False)
ax.set_xticks
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt2 = sns.lineplot(x = 'month' ,y = 'price',
             data=df,ax=ax2,linestyle=':',color="#1167b1", legend=False)
```

I want my chart to look like this for example, so that the red line in the legend stands for the red line in the chart and same for the blue dashed line. Hope you guys can help me.

[image]

Comment: your code is not reproducible

Answer (score 1):

One way is to capture the legend handles and labels, then add them back manually:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
sns.lineplot(x = 'month',y = 'available', data = df2, color="red", 
             label='test1')       # label 

ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt2 = sns.lineplot(x = 'month' ,y = 'price', 
                    data=df, ax=ax2,
                    linestyle=':', color="#1167b1",
                    label='test2')     # label

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()   # capture the handles and labels
ax.legend().remove                     # remove legend on this axis

h2,l2 =ax2.get_legend_handles_labels() # capture the handle and label for 2nd plot
ax2.legend(h+h2, l+l2)                 # add both of them together
```

Output:

[image]